# kendo autocomplete refresh url

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I need refresh the datasource (url) of my Autocomplete widget.

```
factor = tipoSeleccionado.factor;
$cptconcepto.kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 1,
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: "descripcion",
        dataValueField: "idTipoMovimiento",
        dataSource: {
            type: "get",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: pathservicehost + '/movimientos/tipos/' + factor,
                    dataType: "json",                       
                    cache: false
                }
            }
        },
        index: 0
    });
```

"factor" is a variable that constantly changes its value.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple. Just use a function instead of a string in your `read.url` property:

```
url: function() {
    return pathservicehost + '/movimientos/tipos/' + factor;
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ihUDu). In the demo, check the network tab in your dev tools and see that anytime you change the autocomplete value the url changes with the current timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your help ... now the url is changing every time "factor" is modified but now i have a new problem the component "filter: contains" is not working anymore.

Comment: @alexanderzevallos how your url ended with the new implementation ? In the demo, I have commented the `serverFilter` property to make the url clearer, but if I uncomment it, the filters are properly added to the url.